# React error boundary in server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-error-boundary

How can errors in components or their children be caught during server-side rendering? I've seen people using try/catch but apparently a parent's `catch` does not catch errors in their children.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a try-catch block would catch all uncaught errors in child blocks (in this case, components) but I'd have to look at React-specific things. Is this something you're still struggling with or have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi Haden, thank you for you feedback. I have not yet found a solution.